# The method 'dark' isn't defined for the type 'ThemeData'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

I'm getting this errror while following a lecture. ThemeData.dark() is not working properly.

```
import 'package:zoom_clone/screens/login_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Zoom Clone',
      theme: ThemeData().dark(),
      home: const LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData.dark(), // default dark theme replaces default light theme
  home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
 
);
```

Comment: Thank you...It's very problem which waste my time too much but Thanks lot.

Comment: Glad to help you bro.